# Backslashes in secondary tiles URI getting turned into forward slash - WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Hi I got this really irritating problem and I'd like to know if there is some way around it.

The thing is, the secondary tiles I am creating have an URI with a parameter being a path (with backslashes). However, whenever I try to query the active tiles, the path parameter has all its backslashes converted into forward slashes...

Is there another way around this than just replacing all my back slashes by forward slashes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can we see your code? Im guessing something is being escaped incorrectly but without an example its hard to tell.

Comment: Sorry didn't see your answer, I'll update my question when I come back from work.